# Conditionally resetting input element value before submitting form to MVC3 action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

this is probably a simple question but I'm new to jQuery with MVC3. I have an MVC3 application where an Index action lists some papers with their authors. Users can filter the list by (among other parameters) author name, so I have an input element using jQueryUI autocomplete to let them type some letters and pick the desired author. When this happens my JS code stores its ID into a hidden element and posts the form; the ID is then passed via the model binder to an object representing all my filters.

The filters object is like:

```
public sealed class PaperFilter
{
  public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
  // ... other params here
}
```

The controller action receives page number and sort parameters (the view uses the MvcContrib grid) and this filter. It then creates a view model including the list of papers and a number of properties representing the filter properties, and passes it back to the view:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page, GridSortOptions sort, PaperFilter filter)
{
  var papers = _repository.GetPapers(filter);
  if (sort.Column != null)
    papers = papers.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
  ViewBag.Sort = sort;

  PaperIndexModel model = new PaperIndexModel(filter)
    { Papers = papers.AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10) };

  if (filter.AuthorId.HasValue)
  {
    Author author = _repository.GetAuthor((int)filter.AuthorId);
    model.AuthorName = author.FirstName + " " + author.LastName;
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

where the returned model contains the papers list together with a copy of the filter properties.

The view form relevant code is:

```
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AuthorName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AuthorId)
...
```

and its JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#AuthorName").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/Author/FindAuthor", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
          data: { LastName: request.term },
          success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
              return { label: item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName, value: item.LastName, id: item.Id };
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#AuthorName").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#AuthorId").val(ui.item.id);
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This works fine, anyway I'd like my users to reset the author filter by simply clearing the input box (AuthorName) and pressing enter; but to do this I'd need to reset the AuthorId value, i.e. do something like *$("#AuthorId").val("")* before the form is posted. I tried to do this on keypress but it does not seem to fire before the post happens, because my action still gets the filter with its AuthorId populated. Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: i probably don't quite get what you're after, but why can't you simply attach `keypress` event to the autocomplete input?

Comment: Is the issue that the autocomplete will call even if they've cleared out the box?

Comment: Sorry, probably I was not clear. What I'd like to do is providing an easy way of REMOVING the authors filter, and I was thinking of just letting the user CLEAR the input box and press ENTER. This should cause a POST, but the posted parameter for AuthorId should be null, rather than the author ID got when the view was generated after some filtering. So, I must react to ENTER keypress and BEFORE the form is posted I must clear the AuthorId so that the action can regenerate the list without filtering it by author anymore.

Comment: To make my question clearer: for now, I adopted the workaround of adding an element to click for clearing the authors filter. I just add <a href="#" id="ClearAuthor">X</a> in the view, with this JS code:$(function () {
  $("#ClearAuthor").click(function() {
    $("#AuthorName").val("");
    $("#AuthorId").val("");
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

check it right before your .ajax() call. If the length is 0 you don't have to .ajax either and just return.